# Why do I need to press the button 2 times to make this function work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below I have 2 pieces of code. The purpose of the code is to alternate between showing and hiding an element by clicking on the button.

Logically, I feel both pieces of code are sound and should work in exactly the same way. However, #1 functions as required whilst #2 doesn't. #2 requires 2 presses of the button to first display the element. After that, it functions as required.

I assume I have made a mistake linked to nomenclature, but I am unable to pinpoint it. Please help in doing so.

#1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<style>
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  visibility: hidden; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>



<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.visibility === "hidden") {
    x.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    x.style.visibility  = "hidden";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

#2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<style>
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  visibility: hidden; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>



<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.visibility === "visible") {
    x.style.visibility = "hidden";
  } else {
    x.style.visibility  = "visible";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? What does `console.log(x.style.visibility)` give you?

Comment: The `style.visibility` property is not initially set. Change your div to `<div id="myDIV" style="visibility: hidden">`. Remember that the style property refers to *inline* styles, not your CSS.

Comment: @maiorano84 Thanks

Comment: @maiorano84 Also, is there a way to make changes to the CSS style instead of inline style within javascript?

Comment: To change the CSS style, I'd start out by defining a CSS class, then use JS to update the element's class.

Comment: Use a CSS class called "hidden" defined as `.hidden { visibility: hidden; }`, then you can use `x.classList.toggle('hidden')` as the second line in your function (no need to check first).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's happening because the `x.style` returns inline [style](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style.asp) for an element (the value sets on the `div` tag `<div id="myDIV" style="/*this value*/">` and not the overall element styling) which is empty by default , think of it as any other HTML attributes like `id` or `width`.
So what you want to do, is to declare the `visibility` propriety inside the `div` like so :

```
<div id="myDIV" style="visibility: hidden;">
```

this way `x.style.visibility` will return `'hidden'` from the first time.

Here are two snippets so you see the difference:

The same as your code just added a `console.log`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<style>
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  visibility: hidden; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  console.log('x.style.visibility = '+x.style.visibility);
  if (x.style.visibility === "hidden") {
    x.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    x.style.visibility  = "hidden";
  }
}
</script>
<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

and now if we set `visibility` as an inline style

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<style>
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  console.log('x.style.visibility = '+x.style.visibility);
  if (x.style.visibility === "hidden") {
    x.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    x.style.visibility  = "hidden";
  }
}
</script>
<div id="myDIV" style="visibility: hidden;">
This is my DIV element.
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

account for starting condition

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.visibility === "hidden" || !x.style) {
    x.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    x.style.visibility  = "hidden";
  }
}
```